# How to extract that string with HTMLAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to extract the `content` value from a HTML source:

```
<span itemprop="price" content="164,06"></span>
```

with C# using HTMLAgilityPack. My source always responds "nothing found". Any ideas why?

```
private string getTextfrom()
    {

    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = webGet.Load("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zE31NWtU");


    HtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@content]");

    if (priceNode != null) {
        return priceNode.InnerText;
    }

    else
        return "nothing found"; // And this

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
private string getTextfrom()
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    //doc.LoadHtml("<span itemprop=\"price\" content=\"164,06\"></span>");
    string htmlContent = GetPageContent("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zE31NWtU");
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

    HtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span")[0];
    HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = priceNode.Attributes["content"];
    return valueAttribute.Value;
}

public static String GetPageContent(string Url)
{

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What would be if the HTML file actually contains 3 or more span's around. http://pastebin.com/zH8VfJYL

Comment: If you see the line :                                             HtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span")[0];in this the author keep only the first **span**, in you keepHtmlNode priceNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"), this select all the **spans** tags and then the rest works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would also recommend you to use SelectSingle note to fix it to a single note :P